# What is the fastest way to count rows by date in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count the rows having `created_at` `>=` `2019-03-01`.

`created_at` format is like `2018-03-18T14:37:35.000Z`

I noticed that the table uses indexing as follows :
but the created_at doesn't have an index :'(
how can i use the current indexes to speed it up ?

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "Table": "bugs",
            "Non_unique": 0,
            "Key_name": "PRIMARY",
            "Seq_in_index": 1,
            "Column_name": "id",
            "Collation": "A",
            "Cardinality": 9791826,
            "Sub_part": null,
            "Packed": null,
            "Null": "",
            "Index_type": "BTREE",
            "Comment": "",
            "Index_comment": ""
        },
        {
            "Table": "bugs",
            "Non_unique": 1,
            "Key_name": "index_bugs_on_category_and_token_and_reported_at",
            "Seq_in_index": 1,
            "Column_name": "category",
            "Collation": "A",
            "Cardinality": 1,
            "Sub_part": null,
            "Packed": null,
            "Null": "YES",
            "Index_type": "BTREE",
            "Comment": "",
            "Index_comment": ""
        },
        {
            "Table": "bugs",
            "Non_unique": 1,
            "Key_name": "index_bugs_on_category_and_token_and_reported_at",
            "Seq_in_index": 2,
            "Column_name": "token",
            "Collation": "A",
            "Cardinality": 29946,
            "Sub_part": null,
            "Packed": null,
            "Null": "YES",
            "Index_type": "BTREE",
            "Comment": "",
            "Index_comment": ""
        },
        {
            "Table": "bugs",
            "Non_unique": 1,
            "Key_name": "index_bugs_on_category_and_token_and_reported_at",
            "Seq_in_index": 3,
            "Column_name": "reported_at",
            "Collation": "A",
            "Cardinality": 6085027,
            "Sub_part": null,
            "Packed": null,
            "Null": "YES",
            "Index_type": "BTREE",
            "Comment": "",
            "Index_comment": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to do :
`SELECT count(id) FROM table WHERE created_at >= '20190301';`
but it always gives server timeout.

it's worth mentioning that counting rows doesn't timeout the server :
`SELECT count(*) from bugs;`

output :

```
    "records": [
        {
            "count(*)": 10049501
        }
     ]
   }
```

Comment: A link to the "online challenge" might be helpful...

Comment: What is your question?  Didn't you already find the "fastest" way -- that is the one that was fast enough to not time out?

Comment: If `id` cannot be null then `COUNT(*)` can go "[meh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meh)" to the columns, whereas `COUNT(id)` has to consider `id`. I'm not a database specialist.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing `created_at` is the most important thing you can do to optimize your query.

If `created_at` is not indexed, it will have to scan the whole table. If you run `explain SELECT count(id) FROM table WHERE created_at >= '20190301'` you will see something like this:

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE          test                ALL                                                 123     100.00      Using where
```

[`ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#jointype_all) meaning it must scan all 10 million rows.

With an index it can quickly find only those rows where `created_at >= '20190301'`.

```
id  select_type     table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key         key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE          test                range   created_at      created_at  4                   1       100.00      Using where; Using index
```

*However*, if `created_at >= '20190301'` would be a large portion of the table it might decide scanning the whole table is faster than using the index.

---

The second thing you can do is to make sure `created_at` is a [`datetime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) type, not `varchar`. This will store the date as a number and the comparison will be faster. This will not improve performance nearly as much as an index will, but it will help. More importantly, it will make it much easier to work with the values and you can take advantage of [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: thank you so much :D
unfortunately i can't edit the tables, i can only read only,, 
if i used `reported_at` it doesn't timeout since it's an index, i wonder if i can use any of the indexes there to count `created_at` not reported_at ?

Comment: @AYehia0 You *can't* edit the tables, or you're not allowed to? You can't use the index of a column to search a different column. However, if you can figure out a relationship between them you might be able to add a `reported_at` clause that cuts down the number of rows which have to be filtered by `created_at`.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern but I am afraid there isn't any relation in between,,
would you please have a look at this question it's very similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72469648/how-to-speed-select-sql-query

Comment: @AYehia0 Same answer: you need a new index.

Comment: @AYehia0 [Use The Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com/) will help. And if this is for some challenge, a link to the challenge would help us.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is why is the (*) does not time out the answer is this -- in order to count the (id) it has to validate that the id column does not contain null. null is not counted by the count statement. Since the table has 10 million rows it does not finish before the timeout.

Comment: thanks, but i wonder how to count by date, show i convert the time to ISO format, I am trying to count by `created_at >= '2019-03-01'` and the format is `2018-03-18T14:37:35.000Z`

Comment: @AYehia0 1) You do not need to count the `id`, you need to count the rows, i.e. `*`, where the condition holds. 2) Please edit the question to add the database definition of the column `created_at`. N.B. A date does *not* have a format: the string representation of a date has a format.

Comment: @AndrewMorton i edited the question, btw, i can count all the tables but i want to count the rows that have `created_at` > some_date without timing out the server, with the help of the indexes ?

Comment: @AYehia0 You have `SELECT count(id)` but you need `SELECT count(*)`.

Comment: actually it doesn't matter, both works the same (don't timeout) @AndrewMorton