# How to speed SELECT SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to execute a SQL query as fast as I can.

There is only single table with ~10 million records, the table has 3 indexes for faster read, but unfortunately the column I want to select from hasn't.

let me explain :
I want to select the title from table `bugs(id, token, title, category, device, reported_at, created_at, updated_at)` :

What I am doing : `SELECT title FROM (SELECT id FROM bugs WHERE reported_at = '2020-08-30' and token = 'token660')`

it works but it's slow, although I used the 2 indexes reported_at and token, How can I speed it up ?

here are the indexes :

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "Table": "bugs",
            "Non_unique": 0,
            "Key_name": "PRIMARY",
            "Seq_in_index": 1,
            "Column_name": "id",
            "Collation": "A",
            "Cardinality": 9791826,
            "Sub_part": null,
            "Packed": null,
            "Null": "",
            "Index_type": "BTREE",
            "Comment": "",
            "Index_comment": ""
        },
        {
            "Table": "bugs",
            "Non_unique": 1,
            "Key_name": "index_bugs_on_category_and_token_and_reported_at",
            "Seq_in_index": 1,
            "Column_name": "category",
            "Collation": "A",
            "Cardinality": 1,
            "Sub_part": null,
            "Packed": null,
            "Null": "YES",
            "Index_type": "BTREE",
            "Comment": "",
            "Index_comment": ""
        },
        {
            "Table": "bugs",
            "Non_unique": 1,
            "Key_name": "index_bugs_on_category_and_token_and_reported_at",
            "Seq_in_index": 2,
            "Column_name": "token",
            "Collation": "A",
            "Cardinality": 29946,
            "Sub_part": null,
            "Packed": null,
            "Null": "YES",
            "Index_type": "BTREE",
            "Comment": "",
            "Index_comment": ""
        },
        {
            "Table": "bugs",
            "Non_unique": 1,
            "Key_name": "index_bugs_on_category_and_token_and_reported_at",
            "Seq_in_index": 3,
            "Column_name": "reported_at",
            "Collation": "A",
            "Cardinality": 6085027,
            "Sub_part": null,
            "Packed": null,
            "Null": "YES",
            "Index_type": "BTREE",
            "Comment": "",
            "Index_comment": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: did you mean SELECT title FROM bugs WHERE reported_at = '2020-08-30' and token = 'token660' ? your question is not very clear

Comment: Also the index must be in the fields of the conditions, not the select.

Comment: Thanks @LeandroBardelli for replying , doing `SELECT title FROM bugs WHERE reported_at = '2020-08-30' and token = 'token660'` fails as the server times it out, so i thought about selecting by the id and it worked as shown above, also one thing to mention that doing `SELECT id FROM bugs WHERE reported_at = '2020-08-30' and token = 'token660'` works but it's slow

Comment: SELECT title FROM (SELECT id FROM bugs WHERE reported_at = '2020-08-30' and token = 'token660') - can't work since title is not in the subquery?

Comment: Would you like to share the link for this online challenge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***In MySQL***, [multi-column indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) can only use the left-most columns. [Other databases do not have this restriction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html).

This is because MySQL indexes are (by default) [B-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree). A multi-column index is a tree of trees. To use the index `(category, token, reported_at)` MySQL must first find a category in the category tree, then there will be a sub-tree of token's within that category, and finally a sub-tree of reported_at's within that category and token.

In your case, you have a multi-column index on `(category, token, reported_at)`. If you were searching by just category, MySQL could use the index. Or by category and token, MySQL could use the index. Or by category, token, and reported_at.

You're searching by token and reported_at, but since you are not searching by category MySQL will not use the index. It would have to scan every entry in the category index for a matching token. Other databases are more flexible with how they use indexes and might try this anyway, but MySQL will not.

[Use The Index, Luke](https://use-the-index-luke.com) has [a good explanation of multi-column indexes in MySQL](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys)

In general, indexes with more than two columns are of questionable value.

So, [just like before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72469145/14660), the answer is to make a new index on the fields you are searching on. Or use [a better database](https://www.postgresql.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an index with the columns of the search condition. In this case:

```
CREATE INDEX search_index 
ON bugs (reported_at, token);
```

Since you are searching with equal sign this should be fast. The query must be:

```
SELECT title FROM bugs WHERE reported_at = '2020-08-30' and token = 'token660'
```

If you cannot change the database, you can select rows separately, intersect them, and then get the title:

```
SELECT r.title 
FROM (
SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE reported_at = '2020-08-30'
) r
JOIN (
SELECT id FROM bugs WHERE token = 'token660'
) t
ON r.id = t.id
```

Comment: See alternative solution.

Comment: i wonder how's that going to speed it up ?

Comment: would you please check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468990/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-count-rows-by-date-in-mysql

Comment: Since there is no index on `reported_at` nor `token`, selecting each separately and then joining will be even slower; they will do two full table scans.

Comment: @Schwern I can clearly see both indexes in the question.

Comment: @JoeDiNottra That is a single multi-column index called `index_bugs_on_category_and_token_and_reported_at` which is `(category, token, reported_at)`. `Seq_in_index` indicates the position of each column in the index. [MySQL can only use an index if the leftmost columns are in the query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), which means to use the index any query would have to at least search on `category`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  id
    FROM  bugs
    WHERE  reported_at = '2020-08-30'
      and  token = 'token660'
```

needs this *composite* index: `INDEX(token, reported_at)`

I don't know what the rest of the gibberish is about `category` or `title`.